# pass arabic params to PHP exec

Tags: php, terminal, exec, arabic-support

I am trying to pass arabic params to command line using PHP exec function
but the params are received as **blank**.

I am using **PHP 7.0.30, ubuntu 16.4**

```
exec('/jasperphp/src/JasperPHP/../JasperStarter/bin/jasperstarter process test.jasper -f pdf -r /jasperphp/src/JasperPHP/../ -P status="فعال"');
```

and the result of the execution shows blank status instead of "فعال"

**Note**: when I run the command in the terminal it works successfuly, but from PHP it fails.

**Note2**: I have installed Arabic locale

```
$ locale -a
ar_JO.utf8
C
C.UTF-8
en_US.utf8
POSIX
```

how can I pass arabic parameters to exec

Comment: is your php file also utf-8?

Comment: also, you say from PHP it fails. Do you mean from a web server? Apache or NginX? Check the meta tag for charset is also utf-8

Comment: yes I am using Apache Server, I have header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
 at the start of the PHP file , but the param is still blank

Comment: in your IDE, does it say the actual PHP file itself is UTF-8?

Comment: I am using visual studio code, and yes it shows utf-8 at the bottom of the screen

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer in case anyone have the same problem, I had to make a java jar file that takes the report input from php code, and then send these params to jasper  report. (java was like a middle-ware tool)

this way I was able to send Arabic params from php to jasper file without a problem